# Check convergence of $\sum_{n=1} \frac{n+1}{n^3+4n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to check convergence of $\sum_{n=1} \frac{n+1}{n^3+4n}$.

$$\sum_{n=1} \frac{n+1}{n^3+4n}\le \sum_{n=1} \frac{n+1}{n^3}=\sum_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^3}+\sum_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^2}$$

(both series on the right side are obviously convergent)

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Note that there is a tag here called "proof-verification". So if a question is about any request to check the validity of some proposed argument, then the tag should be used.

Comment: As an aside, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac n{n^3+4n} ~=~ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac1{n^2+4} ~=~ \dfrac{2\pi\coth(2\pi)-1}8$. This can be proven by differentiating the natural logarithm of [Euler's infinite product formula for the sine function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still another way to check convergence:

$$\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{n+1}{n^3+4n}\le \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{2}{n^2+4}< 2\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

You found one way.

Another way: Noting that
$$
\frac{n+1}{n^{3}+4n} \cdot n^{2} \to 1
$$
as $n$ grows,
and that the series $\sum_{n} n^{-2}$ converges,
by the limit comparison test we have the convergence of the series $\sum_{n}\frac{n+1}{n^{3}+4n}$.

Comment: What does precisely ~ symbol mean?

Comment: @mark34 Hey that is an asymptotic notation for what you see now :)

Comment: In term of limits it means that they are arbitraly close each other when $n$ is big?